# python IOerror: [Errno 22] Invalid argument from threading.thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I try to write to sysfs form a threading.thread

it works without threading:

```
f = open('/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/duty_cycle', 'w')
f.write(str(100))
f.close()
```

but if I place it in a thread:

```
import threading

class Thread(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)

   def run(self):
       while True:
          f = open('/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/duty_cycle', 'w')
          f.write(str(100))
          f.close()
          time.sleep(1)

 t = Thread()
 t.start()
```

it results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/steve/test.py", line 10, in run
    f.close()
```

IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

If f.flush() is added before f.close() same error happens at f.flush().
As it seems threads does not have same permission to sysfs as the main thread.
Even adding a lock arround the write block does not prevent it.
Why is this the case and how can I get around it?